# Android: How to place a linear layout showing a image at the bottom of a layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have used LinearLayout in my activity, in that I need to display another LinearLayout containing image to be displayed at the bottom.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:background="@drawable/gamelevelscreen"
android:orientation="vertical" >
.......
            <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout_AdMob"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center">
            </LinearLayout>  
</LinearLayout>
```

But the image is not completely aligned at the bottom. Its a little above the bottom.
I have completed the layout designing and it will be a lot of rework to make it Relative now. Kindly give solution to make it happen in LinearLayout only.

Comment: `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` has no effect in `LinearLayout`. Consider using `RelativeLayout` instead.

Comment: @antimo Is it impossible to do so in LinearLayout? I have completed the layout designing and it will be a lot of rework to make it Relative now.

Comment: You can use `android:layout_weight` in your `LinearLayout` to fill the rest of the space, and then put the content on bottom with `android:gravity="bottom"`

Comment: I was encountering the same issue. You need to go for the relativelayout.

Answer (score 3):

Use Relative layout instead of Linear layout or use Weight for doing this in Linear layout.
Try this it will surely help you.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout_AdMob"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout_AdMob"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gamelevelscreen"
android:orientation="vertical" >
            <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout_AdMob"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
            </LinearLayout>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout_AdMob"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```